# redis not starting - Opening Unix socket: bind: Address already in use

Tags: redis

I don't know why systemctl is not capable to start redis, however I can start redis manually. What I mean is:

systemctl start redis --> does not work, I can see a message `Opening Unix socket: bind: Address already in use` in the log files

I don't have another instance of redis running...

any idea?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?